# Seconds left for the time in the future?

Tags: c#, time, timespan

I have the following Code:

```
var enteredDate = Convert.ToDateTime("17:45");
var todaysDateTime = DateTime.Now;
var span = enteredDate.Subtract(todaysDateTime);
double totalMins = Math.Ceiling(span.TotalMinutes);

string timeCond;
if (totalMins > 0)
{
   if (totalMins < 5)
   {
     timeCond = Math.Ceiling(span.TotalSeconds) + " seconds left.";
   }
   else
   {
     timeCond = totalMins + " minutes left.";
   }
```

}

Given that the time now would be `17:50` the returned second would be a negative figure, I would like to be able to return the seconds or minutes in relation to the code for the next time the time would be `17:45`, is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: I did try it, that's why I was asking

Comment: I'm bummed, I expected this question to tell us how many seconds we had left to live before Armageddon! I wanted to see the algorithm on how the final point in future time was calculated! :-P

Comment: @Dylan sorry to burst your bubble :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just add a day:

```
var span = enteredDate - todaysDateTime;
if (span < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    span += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
```

(Note that this assumes there are 24 hours between today's 17:45 and tomorrow's 17:45. That isn't true around daylight saving transitions; accommodating for that is feasible, but would make life somewhat more complicated.)

Comment: Accommodating for DST changes has led to me breathing a deep sigh of relief every time I drive through Saskatchewan.

Comment: Thanks, I just went totally blank on that way, thanks for the hint, now it's working as it should, as for DST I'll leave that for a rainy day. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var span = Convert.ToDateTime("17:45") > DateTime.Now ? Convert.ToDateTime("17:45") - DateTime.Now : Convert.ToDateTime("17:45").AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now
```